# Electromagnetic radiation emission

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

Does Bremsstrahlung radiation produce only a certain type of electromagnetic radiation (for example X-ray) or can it also produce visible light when the trajectory of the incoming electron is not affected a lot.

This video might help to understand the question:
 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D0QOHUQSjtvI&ved=2ahUKEwi55r_P4ODnAhVkxIsKHXFlBH4Qt9IBMA96BAgNECo&usg=AOvVaw1b9AgrTYlfESSYlLb5GP74

Comment: One might suggest that visible light emission is much more likely to be from other processes in the solid (particularly if a semiconductor or insulator). But, you can crank through the Brems formula to see what it predicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have visible wavelength bremsstrahlung. There are many setups available, one of them is when you use a Large Helical Device, an 84 inch optical fiber array, an interference filter and 84 photomultipliers.

> Visible bremsstrahlung emission has been
>   measured by two diagnostics in NBl-heated discharges
>   of LHD. The contribution of line emissions was
>   estimated to be 20-30 Vo by separating the continuum
>   emission in the visible spectrum measured by the
>   spectrometer.

http://www.jspf.or.jp/JPFRS/PDF/Vol5/jpfrs2002_05-442.pdf

Just to clarify, the wavelength of bremsstralung can theoretically be any wavelength, though, our experiments and energy levels limit the emitted photons' wavelength.

> Bremsstrahlung has a continuous spectrum, which becomes more intense and whose peak intensity shifts toward higher frequencies as the change of the energy of the decelerated particles increases.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung